# Jquery appending undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm having issues with appending a json. It print's multiple undefineds and i'm unsure what the cause is.

My code:

```
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/503aj", function(obj) {
      $.each(obj, function(key, test) {
        $("ul").append("<div>" + test.CustomerRef + "</div>" + "<div>" + obj.CustomerName + "</div>" + "<div>" + test.DelAddress1 + "</div>");
      });
    });
  });
```

Linked js fiddle showing the issue;

https://jsfiddle.net/7vshmzj7/

Why does it do it? and what are the possible workarounds?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put the full code and JSON **in** the question.

Comment: it stems from not knowing what $.each is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you're getting back looks like this:

```
{
    "AddressData": {
        "OrderNo": "4200",
        "CustomerRef": "A1011",
        "DelAddress1": "4 Test Road",
        "DelAddress2": "Testing Lane",
        "DelAddress3": "Testland",
        "DelAddress4": "UK",
        "DelPostCode": "DB11 8DA"
    },
    "CustomerRef": "A1011",
    "CustomerName": "John Doe",
    "CustomerData": {
        "Email": "JohnDoe2500@gmail.com",
        "Phone": "07785442"
    }
}
```

That's not something you have to loop through with `$.each`, and looping through it with `$.each` is the problem.

Just use it directly:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/503aj", function(obj) {
        $("ul").append("<div>" + obj.CustomerRef + "</div>" + "<div>" + obj.CustomerName + "</div>" + "<div>" + obj.AddressData.DelAddress1 + "</div>");
    });
});
```

Note that the three fields you're accessing are accessed in that like this:

- `obj.CustomerRef`
- `obj.CustomerName`
- `obj.AddressData.DelAddress1`

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vshmzj7/2/)